# CSS custom properties placement :root vs body/html tags

Tags: css, css-variables

What is the point to define global CSS custom properties in a `:root` instead of `body` or `html` tags. Is this will lead to different effects or perfomance issues?

Comment: actually `:root` is `<html>`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:root

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, it might be weird initially, but it is nothing about it except [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). [`:root`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:root) is actually `html` itself with a higher specificity, so the main reason for putting variables in `:root` element is because we are not only using them in CSS but also in SVG and XML. So we may call `:root` global scope as its usage. You can also [read more about their differences](https://css-tricks.com/breaking-css-custom-properties-out-of-root-might-be-a-good-idea/).